# Create columns' name based on lines' value in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, view, mariadb

**T1** is a table that contains all the values I want as a column name:

```
---------------
|      T1     |
---------------
|  id  |  v1  |
---------------
|  1   |  a   |
---------------
|  2   |  b   |
---------------
|  3   |  c   |
---------------
```

**T2** is a table that contains all my data:

```
-------------------------------
|             T2              |
-------------------------------
|  id  |  art  |  t1v1  |  v1 |
-------------------------------
|  1   |   10  |   a    |  z  |
-------------------------------
|  2   |   10  |   c    |  y  |
-------------------------------  
|  3   |   11  |   a    |  x  |
-------------------------------
|  4   |   11  |   b    |  w  |
-------------------------------
|  5   |   11  |   c    |  v  |
-------------------------------
```

**T3** is the view I want to create. The columns' name are the values from the column named **v1** in **T1**:

```
---------------------------
|            T3           |
---------------------------
|  art  |  a  |  b  |  c  |
---------------------------
|   10  |  z  |     |  y  |
---------------------------
|   11  |  x  |  w  |  v  |
---------------------------
```

I tried a lot of solutions using `GROUP_CONCAT` in `SELECT` but I didn't find anything to create multiple columns based on line values. Is there a way to create that kind of views ?

Comment: Do you have more rows in table T1? And please update the question with query you have tried

Comment: @CharveeShah Yes it is just a small example and the real table contains a lot more values that could change in the future.